# Where does a sparkly (CO$_2$) water bottle have more presure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

Where does a sparkly (CO$_2$) water bottle have more pressure? At a higher altitude (7000 feet) or under sea level (-8 feet)?

Answer (score 1):

If the bottle is open, the pressure is whatever the local atmospheric pressure is. If it's closed, then your answer is going to depend on your bottle. If the bottle is air tight, then you can expect the internal pressure to be insensitive to the external pressure, and therefore, the pressure inside will be whatever the manufacturer made it to be.

Comment: NB this is a good answer to v3 of the question.